# Function not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function set up as an API for our Citrix environment. What happens is an icon is loaded and displayed. Once it is clicked on it will launch using the below code. This works fine in IE11 and Chrome, but when clicking on it in IE9 nothing happens. Do I need to add something to get it to work with IE9?

```js
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var $configXml, resourcesData, url;

$(document).ready(function () {
      
  // Web Proxy request to fetch the configuration
  ajaxWrapper({ url: 'Home/Configuration', dataType: 'xml', success: configSuccess });

  $('form').submit(function () {
    var username = $('#username').val(),
    password = $('#password').val();

    clearMessage();

    if (!username || !password) {
      showMessage('Enter a username and a password');
      return false;
    }

    // Ensure the user name is correct...
    // If the username has the domain string at position 0, then
    // the username is correct and just use it as normal, but if
    // not, username needs to have the domain prepended.
    // Because of the backslashes in the strings, they need to be 
    // escaped with "\\"
    username = username.indexOf("DOMAIN\\") === 0 ? username : "DOMAIN\\" + username;

    // Web Proxy request to log the user on
    ajaxWrapper({
      url: 'PostCredentialsAuth/Login',
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: loginSuccess,
      error: loginError,
      data: { username: username, password: password }
    });

    return false;
  });

        $('#log-off').click(function () {
            // Web Proxy request to log the user off
            url = ($configXml.find('authManager').attr('logoffURL'));
            ajaxWrapper({ url: url, dataType: 'text', success: logoffSuccess });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function configSuccess(data) {
        $configXml = $(data);
        // The userLanguages setting reflects the browser's Accept-Language header, which can be used to localize the client UI
        // var languages = $configXml.find('session').attr('userLanguages');

        // Web Proxy request to enumerate the available authentication methods
        ajaxWrapper({ url: 'Authentication/GetAuthMethods', dataType: 'xml', success: getAuthMethodsSuccess });
    };

    function getAuthMethodsSuccess(xmlData) {
        var url;

        $(xmlData).find('method').each(function (index, elt) {
            var name = $(elt).attr("name"),
                authUrl = $(elt).attr("url");

            if (name == 'PostCredentials') {
                url = authUrl;
                return false; // Break out of the 'each' loop
            } else {
                return true; // Continue iterating
            }
        });

        if (url) {
            showLogonForm();
        } else {
            showMessage('PostCredentials authentication is not available - check HttpBasic is enabled at the Authentication service');
        }
    }

    function loginSuccess(data) {
        var $loginXml = $(data),
            result = $loginXml.find('Result').text();

        if (result == 'success') {
            $('form').hide();
            $('#log-off').show();
   
   var idleTime;
   $(document).ready(function () {
     reloadPage();
     $('html').bind('mousemove click mouseup mousedown keydown keypress keyup submit change mouseenter scroll resize dblclick', function () {
      clearTimeout(idleTime);
      reloadPage();
     });
   });
   function reloadPage() {
    clearTimeout(idleTime);
    idleTime = setTimeout(function () {
     location.reload();
    }, 600000);
   }

            // Web Proxy request to enumerate the resources available to the user
            url = $configXml.find('resourcesProxy').attr('listURL');
            ajaxWrapper({ url: url, success: listResourcesSuccess });
        } else {
            showMessage('Login failed - try again');
        }
    }

    function loginError() { console.log('Login failed'); }

    function logoffSuccess() {
        showMessage('You have logged off successfully');
        showLogonForm();
  $('#log-off').hide();
    }

    function showLogonForm() {
        $('#resources-container').empty();
        $('form').show();
  document.forms[0].reset();
        $('#username').select().focus();
    }

    function listResourcesSuccess(data) {
        var markup = '';

        resourcesData = data.resources;
  

        for (var i = 0; i < resourcesData.length; i++) {
            markup += generateResourceMarkup(resourcesData[i], i);
        }
  

        $('#resources-container').append($(markup))
                                 .off('click')
                                 .on('click', '.resource', null, prepareLaunch);
  

  $("div p").parent('div').hide();
  $("div p:contains('Clairvia')").parent('div').show();
   

        // Web Proxy request to fetch the user's full name
        url = ($configXml.find('authManager').attr('getUsernameURL'));
        ajaxWrapper({ url: url, dataType: 'text', success: getUsernameSuccess });
    }

    function getUsernameSuccess(data) {
        showMessage('Welcome ' + encodeHtml(data));
    }

    function prepareLaunch() {
        var index = $(this).attr('id'),
            resource = resourcesData[index];

        console.log('launch: ' + resource.name);

        if ($.inArray('ica30', resource.clienttypes) == -1) {
            console.log('Resource does not support ICA launch');
            return;
        }

        // Web Proxy request to check whether the resource is ready to launch
        ajaxWrapper({ url: resource.launchstatusurl, success: launchStatusSuccess, error: launchStatusError });

        function launchStatusSuccess(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            if (xhr.getResponseHeader('CitrixWebReceiver-Authenticate')) {
                // If the Web Proxy session has terminated for any reason, this authentication challenge header is returned.
                // After authentication, all calls to the Web Proxy should be prepared to deal with this challenge, typically
                // by prompting the user to log on again.
                console.log('No session - user must log in again');
                return;
            }

            console.log('launch status: ' + data.status);
            // Note, data.status is set to 'retry' if a desktop VM needs to be started up by the server.
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                performLaunch(resource);
            }
        }

        function launchStatusError() { console.log('Get launch status failed'); }
    }

    function performLaunch(resource) {
        var icaFileUrl = resource.launchurl,
            csrfToken = getCookie('CsrfToken'),
            currentTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
            frameId = "launchframe_" + currentTime;

        // To initiate a launch, an ICA file is loaded into a hidden iframe.
        // The ICA file is returned with content type "application/x-ica", allowing it to be intercepted by the Citrix HDX
        // browser plug-in in Firefox/Chrome/Safari. For IE, the user may be prompted to open the ICA file.
        $('#hidden-iframes').append('<iframe id="' + frameId + '" name="' + frameId + '"></iframe>');

        if (csrfToken != null) {
            icaFileUrl = updateQueryString(icaFileUrl, "CsrfToken", csrfToken);
        }

        // Web Proxy request to load the ICA file into an iframe
        // The request is made by adding
        icaFileUrl = updateQueryString(icaFileUrl, 'launchId', currentTime);
        $("#" + frameId).attr('src', icaFileUrl);

        console.log('perform launch - url: ' + icaFileUrl);
    }

    function generateResourceMarkup(resource, index) {
        var result = '<div id="' + index + '" class="resource">';

        result += '<img class="resource-icon" alt="' + encodeHtmlForAttr(resource.name) + '" src="' + resource.iconurl + '">';
        result += '<p class="resource-name">' + encodeHtml(resource.name) + '</p>';
        result += '</div>';

        return result;
    }

    function showMessage(message) { $('#message').text(message); }

    function clearMessage() { showMessage(''); }

    function getCookie(name) {
        var results = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + name + '=([^;]*)');
        return results ? unescape(results[2]) : null;
    }

    function updateQueryString(url, key, value) {
        var re = new RegExp("([?|&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
        if (url.match(re)) {
            return url.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
        } else {
            return url + (url.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '?') + key + "=" + value;
        }
    }

    function encodeHtml(value) {
        return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
    }

    // Additionally encode double quotes to allow values to be used within double-quoted HTML attributes
    function encodeHtmlForAttr(value) {
        return encodeHtml(value).replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
    }

    function ajaxWrapper(options) {
        var defaultOptions = {
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            beforeSend: function (jqXHR) {
                var csrfToken = getCookie('CsrfToken');
                if (csrfToken != null) {
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Csrf-Token", csrfToken);
                }
                var isUsingHttps = location.protocol.toLowerCase() == "https:" ? "Yes" : "No";
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Citrix-IsUsingHTTPS", isUsingHttps);
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('Ajax error accessing URL: ' + options.url);
            }
        };

        options = $.extend({}, defaultOptions, options);
        $.ajax(options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is `$(this)` insie the function? I am not seeing any jquery object

Comment: what does your console say when you click it? It's probably some builtin method you're using

Comment: IE9 -  console.* only work when the dev tools are open, if the dev tools are not open it errors out & your script will terminate.

Comment: So did you debug to see why it is not working? :) Any errors, etc... The code is also not complete so could be something else....

Comment: I have updated the code to include the full script. What is weird is it will not work currently. If I press F12 which brings up the dev console, while it is open it works as expected?

Comment: Yes, see my earlier comment, you need a shim for console in IE9

Comment: Ok so I have found some fixes for it, but do I need to place those fixes everywhere console is defined or at the beginning before the script?

Comment: Ok, I just remove the console.log options from those sections which fixed the issue. Thank you.